# Updated Magento 1.9.2.2 Blank Admin but Frontend Works

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

We received a couple questions about blank admins after upgrading to Magento 1.9.2.2 but the frontend of the store was working properly. There was no errors being returned on admin or on server logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We pulled a copy of the entire store and took a look and on both occasions we saw that there was missing files inside the app/design/adminhtml and skin/adminhtml

What we did was pull down a new copy of Magento 1.9.2.2 and push up the missing files. Then manually cleared the cache and session by deleting var/cache and var/sessions

It should be noted that in both instances there was only missing adminhtml files but that might not necessarily be the case in every situation. We used a tool called Beyond Compare to review the file/folder structure and contents but Im sure there are others out there.